# How to generate all possible combinations n-bit strings?

Tags: matlab, bit-manipulation

Given a positive integer n, I want to generate all possible n bit combinations in matlab.
For ex : If n=3, then answer should be

```
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

How do I do it ?
I want to actually store them in matrix. I tried

```
for n=1:2^4 
r(n)=dec2bin(n,5); 
end;
```

but that gave error "In an assignment A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just loop over all integers in `[0,2^n)`, and print the number as binary.  If you always want to have `n` digits (e.g. insert leading zeros), this would look like:

```
for ii=0:2^n-1,
    fprintf('%0*s\n', n, dec2bin(ii));
end
```

**Edit:** there are a number of ways to put the results in a matrix.  The easiest is to use

```
x = dec2bin(0:2^n-1);
```

which will produce an `n`-by-`2^n` matrix of type `char`.  Each row is one of the bit strings.

If you really want to store strings in each row, you can do this:

```
x = cell(1, 2^n);
for ii=0:2^n-1,
    x{ii} = dec2bin(ii);
end
```

However, if you're looking for efficient processing, you should remember that integers are already stored in memory in binary!  So, the vector:

```
x = 0 : 2^n-1;
```

Contains the binary patterns in the most memory efficient and CPU efficient way possible.  The only trade-off is that you will not be able to represent patterns with more than 32 of 64 bits using this compact representation.

Comment: I want to actually store them in matrix. I tried 
for n=1:2^4
r(n)=dec2bin(n,5);
end;
but that gave error "In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same."

Comment: or a more efficient version: s = dec2bin(0:2^n-1)

Comment: @HappyMittal: The key idea is that the "patterns" are just the integers from 0 to 2^n-1.  Do you want a matrix of `n`-by-`2^n` booleans, or a cell array of `2^n` strings of length `n`?

Comment: 'ii' may start from 1 i guess? furthermore, in cells, the all zero and one 1 elements are being represented as {'1'}

Answer (score 1):

This is a one-line answer to the question which gives you a double array of all `2^n` bit combinations:

`bitCombs =  dec2bin(0:2^n-1) - '0'`

Answer (score 0):

So many ways to do this permutation. If you are looking to implement with an array counter:  set an array of counters going from 0 to 1 for each of the three positions (2^0,2^1,2^2).  Let the starting number be 000 (stored in an array). Use the counter and increment its  1st place (2^0). The number will be 001. Reset the counter at position (2^0) and increase counter at 2^1 and go on a loop till you complete all the counters.